# how to go to a specific folder directly from jasper server community edition main menu bar custom menu item

Tags: jasperserver

I added new menu for main menu bar in Jasper Server Community Edition.then I want to set a direct link for my custom folders in that custom menu items.

When I go to two folders URL is same for both.It is also equal to Repository URL that I shown below as **common url**.

**common url is :-** 
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=searchFlow

How can I find folder specific url in jasper server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not documented, the samples in the [Repository HTTP API](https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v640/repository-http-api) use the `folderUri` URL parameter for navigating inside repository folders:

```
http://<host>:<port>/<context>/flow.html?_flowId=searchFlow&folderUri=/public/Samples/Reports
```

I have tried this in latest JasperReports Server(v7.1) and it works properly.

One important thing I have noticed is that the value for this parameter is case-sensitive. You could obtain the right value by performing these steps:

1. Right-click the Repository folder for which you need the path
2. Select the `Properties...` option
3. Copy the `Path` value from the pop-up dialog

Comment: In JasperReports Server(v6.4.2) it's not working for me.

Comment: I have just installed a fresh JasperReports Server Community Edition (v6.4.2) for macosx and got it working(creating direct URLs to repository folders). You need to describe all the steps you took for achieving this, from login to URL creation.

Comment: Did you do javascript building after link addition? Because I didn't do that